# Does Cylinder misfire mean buy new engine?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, impala

Impala ltz 2006 misfire cylinder check engine light keep blinking do can it be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you actually had the codes checked to ensure you are getting a misfire ... could be something else. Just suggesting you check to make sure.

Comment: most common misfiring cause is poor maintainance of spark plugs/ loose connections, which is an easy and inexpensive fix, get a mechanic to check your engine first if you obd scanner is not helping.

Answer (score 4):

Of course is doesn't. A misfire could be caused by a number of issues:

- Spark Plug
- Injector
- Wiring
- Ignition Coil
- HT Lead (if fitted)
- ECU

which are all reasonably easy to fix.

More rarely it could be a number of internal faults:

- Burn't or worn vavles
- Worn or broke Cam Shaft
- Bent Con Rod (usually caused by water ingestion)
- Burn't or damaged piston

fixing these issues require varying amounts of engine dismantling from simply removing the rocker cover and timing gear to a total rebuild.

I would say 99% of the time a misfire is cause by one of the top electrical faults.

Answer (score 0):

I went to AutoZone and got a diagnostic test the readout said Cylinder 6 misfire or is not firing but then later on this week my engine check light went off by itself but it's not running as the engine is not running smooth like it was so I still think there's misfire and something wrong with the check engine light